# Git: How can I modify server's commit?

Tags: git

I have already push some commits on my git server on EC2 , not on github.

How can I modify those commits on the git server?

Operation like
remove commit, like rebasing, 
change commit message

Is it possible?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do just about everything with a forced push. Change your local tree to exactly what you want and `git push -f` and it will replace the tree on the server with what you have locally. It's worth noting that this will cause trouble with any other repos that have pulled the tree you just replaced.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to edit a remote branch's history destructively (e.g. `rebase`/`amend`), make your changes locally and then do `git push --force`. Sometimes it does not work (repository administrators can disable this feature); in that case, you can try deleting the remote branch with `git push origin :my_branch` and then pushing it again with `git push origin my_branch`. Otherwise you can use `git revert`, which is the recommended way if you work in a team (the rule of thumb is that published history should not be modified).

Here's an example (using [this Github repository](https://github.com/23Skidoo/ghc-parmake)):

```
$ touch SOMETHING
$ emacs SOMETHING 
$ git add SOMETHING 
$ git ci -m SOMETHING
[master d14aaa0] SOMETHING
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 SOMETHING
$ git push
Counting objects: 8, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 611 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:23Skidoo/ghc-parmake.git
   53f836a..d14aaa0  master -> master
$ git reset --hard "HEAD~"
HEAD is now at 7b2dc96 TODO update.
$ git push --force
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:23Skidoo/ghc-parmake.git
 + d14aaa0...7b2dc96 master -> master (forced update)
```

Looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/23Skidoo/ghc-parmake/commits/master), you can see that commit d14aaa0 is absent.