# How to rebase (squeeze) last commits to master and change commit message

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

In GitI have following situation:

```
o "ok" b6ca869   [my_branch*]
|
o "ok" 479d27c
|
o "ok" c80fad5
|
o "ok" 8f7fe87
|
o "master commit message" [master][remotes/origin/master]
```

I want to squeeze those 4 "ok" commits to and furthermore change the message

```
o "my_branch commit message"    [my_branch*]
|
o "master commit message" [master][remotes/origin/master]
```

So what I do is

```
git rebase --interactive master
```

And GNU nano (I'm on Ubuntu) editor is opened

```
GNU nano 2.2.2             File: /home/.git/modules/src/android/frameworks/base/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo                                

pick 8f7fe87 ok
pick c80fad5 ok
pick 479d27c ok
pick b6ca869 ok

# Rebase aeedb8f..b6ca869 onto aeedb8f
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

**As I understand I have to edit this file, but actually I don't know how.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to squash the last 3 commits to the first one so(`s` stands for `squash`):

```
pick 8f7fe87 ok
s c80fad5 ok
s 479d27c ok
s b6ca869 ok
```

Save and then exit, and a new buffer should popup with all the commit messages. Simply use/modify the commit that you want to have at the end, save and exit.

Comment: works perfect, thanks. this answer was first so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

you can squash together the last 4 commits; since you committed them locally. To do that you would edit the file to:

```
pick 8f7fe87 ok
s c80fad5 ok
s 479d27c ok
s b6ca869 ok
```

after that you will be able to change the (combined) commit message.

***However*** this will not squash them on the last commit with "master commit message". The problem is that your "master commit" has been pushed to the server; so you cannot simply append commits to a commit that has been pushed to the server.

That commit has a certain "hash" code; and since other users might have pulled that code; git does not (or not easily) allow to append to a commit that has already been pushed to the server. If you want to do that, you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815626/git-how-can-i-modify-servers-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Change the three lower `pick`s to `squash`, then save and exit. Another editor will pop up, allowing you to change the commit message.

If you want to undo the rebase for any reason, have a look at `git reflog`. It will show you the sha1 of the state before the rebase, and you can return to that state by doing a `git reset --hard sha1`. There also is a shortcut to reference the reflog, `git reset --hard @{1}`

Comment: Did you mean `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`?

Comment: That's two different things, but both work. "@{1}" references the previous state of the current branch. (See git-rev-parse(1))